# Seq[Either[A, B]] => Either[A, Seq[B]] Function

Tags: scala

I wrote a function of type `Seq[Either[String,Int]] => Either[String, Seq[Int]]`

```
scala> xs
res11: List[Either[String,Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(55))

scala> acc
res12: Either[String,Seq[Int]] = Right(List())

scala> xs.foldLeft(acc){ (acc, elem) => {
     |     acc.right.flatMap(list => elem.right.map(_ +: list) )
     | }}
res10: Either[String,Seq[Int]] = Right(List(55, 1))
```

Please review my `foldLeft` solution. Perhaps there's a higher order function that can more elegantly do this work?

Comment: You haven't written a function.  There's no `def` in there.  It seems you've demonstrated the execution sequence which could be rewritten as a function.  Why not write up the actual function properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few points:

1. Your implementation reverses the order of elements if it succeeds (i.e. if they're all rights). I'm assuming this isn't intentional?
2. You're taking a list but returning a `Seq`. This may be what you want, but I find it a little confusing.
3. The inner curly brackets are unnecessary (and I personally find them kind of noisy).
4. I'd strongly suggest not shadowing the external `acc` with the accumulator function argument.

So I'd probably write it like this:

```
val xs: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(55))

xs.foldRight(Right(Nil): Either[String, List[Int]]) { (elem, acc) =>
  acc.right.flatMap(list => elem.right.map(_ :: list))
}
```

Or:

```
xs.foldRight(Right(Nil): Either[String, List[Int]]) { (elem, acc) =>
  for {
    t <- acc.right
    h <- elem.right
  } yield h :: t
}
```

But that's only if I couldn't use [cats](https://github.com/non/cats) or [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), both of which provide this operation as `sequenceU`:

```
scala> import cats._, cats.syntax.traverse._, cats.std.all._
import cats._
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.std.all._

scala> val xs: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(55))
xs: List[Either[String,Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(55))

scala> xs.sequenceU
res0: scala.util.Either[String,List[Int]] = Right(List(1, 55))
```

Which is much nicer.

Comment: +1 for foldRight.  When you say "You're taking a list but returning a Seq", well no.  Having a function which has a signature taking an input of type Seq and returning one is *good*.  More generic and when given a list, if written properly, it'll return one.  What is confusing is using a list in that function's implementation.  But then the OP hasn't formally defined a function, just typed into the repl a sequence showing how it could be written.

Comment: @itsbruce It's hard to say without knowing more about the OP's intent (as you say, there's nothing like a method signature to make that clear). There are plenty of cases where it you wouldn't want to lose the static information that what you're working with is a `List`.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the most glamorous solution (feel free to efficientiate) to the problem, but you could always...

```
    def transmogrify[A, B](someSeq: Seq[Either[A, B]]): Either[A, Seq[B]] = {
      if (someSeq.exists(_.isLeft)) Left(someSeq.collect( { case Left(anA: A) => anA }).head)
      else Right(someSeq.collect { case Right(aB: B) => aB })
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.